# How does Rails know which controller's "show" action to use in this example from Rails Guides?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, actioncontroller

I'm reviewing the ["Rails Routing From The Outside In"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) section of the Rails Guides, and I came across this section:

> Sometimes, you have a resource that clients always look up without
>   referencing an ID. For example, you would like /profile to always show
>   the profile of the currently logged in user. In this case, you can use
>   a singular resource to map /profile (rather than /profile/:id) to the
>   show action:
>
> ```
> get 'profile', to: 'users#show'
> ```
>
> Passing a String to match will expect a controller#action format,
>   while passing a Symbol will map directly to an action:
>
> ```
> get 'profile', to: :show
> ```

The guide says that 'passing a Symbol will map directly to an action', but let's say I have multiple controllers which each have a 'show' action.  How does Rails know which one to use, since I'm no longer referencing a specific controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That documentation is somewhat misleading, isn't it.  It is a poor example.  The comment about passing symbols to match is a general comment, and should be outside the section on singular resources.

Indeed if you try it stand-alone, you will get the following error when starting Rails or running `rake routes`:

```
rake routes
rake aborted!
missing :controller
```

So you would have to add a `:controller` option for that to work outside of a resource declaration:

```
get 'profile', to: :show, controller: 'users'
```

The syntax they specify IS valid inside of a `resources` or `resource` declaration, e.g.:

```
resources :user do
  collection do
    get 'profile', to: :show
  end
end
```

or

```
resource :user do
  get 'profile', to: :show
end
```

However both those examples generate different routes from the prior example.  So again, I think the comment is misplaced.

Comment: It seems that the line `get 'profile', to: 'users#show', controller: 'users'`should be `get 'profile', to: :show, controller: 'users'`. The `controller` option has no effect if we write the line in the first way.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that it does not know...

```
#config/routes.rb

get 'profile', to: :show
```

From console:

```
$ rake routes
rake aborted
missing :controller
```

The first example: 'users#show', does create a successful route, as does

```
get 'profile', to: :show, controller: 'users'
```